# Google Not Indexing Site - Says 'Blocked by Robots.txt' - However Robots.txt allows all crawlers -- Same problem with two different hosting services

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, robots.txt, google-search-console, google-index

I have built and published quite a few websites and never had the following issue:

Google is not indexing my website. Whenever I submit the page (in Google Search Console) it says "***blocked by robots.txt***" although the **robots.txt** allows every crawler (`User-agent: *` and `Allow: /`). The robots.txt is accessible via `mydomain.com/robots.txt` and the site's sitemap is accessible via `mydomain.com/sitemap`.

I have tried it with two different hosting providers: *Dreamhost.com* and *Fastcomet.com*. The issue persists however, and I cannot see why. The domains are registered with *Namecheap.com* which I have been using for many other sites since forever.

I use [Grav CMS](https://getgrav.org) -- a terrific flat-file CMS -- which usually works flawlessly and I don't think that the CMS causes the problem.

Here below is a screenshot of Google's error message inside Google Search Console. Obviously, **the robots.txt cannot be the culprit**, since crawlers are allowed access.

Lastly, not even the domain is coming up in Google's search results. Usually, Google displays a domain without the accompanying description etc., if it is not allowed to crawl that domain.

[image]

Comment: What does https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool say?

Comment: @CBroe -- thanks for asking. I have managed to solve it. I did not know that one must proactively re-submit the updated robots.txt before anything else. At a very early stage, all crawlers were blocked in the robots.txt. Later, when submitting the final site on Google Search Console for indexing, Google would not index it, only showing a generic error message, not even mentioning an error code etc. Why don't they say that one must re-submit the updated robots.txt separately before one can submit the site for indexation. What a mess! I will write an extensive answer here when I have more time.

Comment: Googlebot fetches your robots.txt once every 24 hours.  You don't need to re-submit it, but you do need to wait 24 hours after changing it before submitting anything else.